# Any idea why I am getting a segmentation fault?

Tags: arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

OK, so I am new to C and cannot figure out why this won't work. The output is just says (null) segmentation fault.

I have an array of structs (Address), which I have dynamically allocated along with the pointers contained in the Address structs.  I am trying to sort the addresses by street names so I have to parse through the string and get the substring that comes after the initial whitespace.  For example: for '123 Anywhere St.', I have to get the substring 'Anywhere St.' to compare those strings for sorting.

What am I doing wrong that could be causing this?

```
/*Prints the array sorted from a-z by street name*/
void printStreetSortedArray(Address * array, int total)
{
    int i;
    int j, k, z;
    char temp1[256], *sub_string1;
    char temp2[256], *sub_string2;
    Address tmpAdd;

    for(i=0; i<total-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<total; j++)
        {
            //Get the two substrings (street names) for comparison
            strcpy(temp1, array[i].street);
            z = 0;
            while(temp1[z] != ' ')
            {
                z++;
            }
            sub_string1 = temp1+z+1;

            strcpy(temp2, array[j].street);
            z = 0;
            while(temp2[z] != ' ')
            {
                z++;
            }
            sub_string2 = temp2+z+1;

            //Compare street names and swap addresses
            if(strcasecmp(sub_string2, sub_string1) < 0)
            {
                tmpAdd = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = tmpAdd;
            }
        }
    }

    //If I print using this format, it will work correctly
    /*printAddress(array[0]);
    printf("\n");
    printAddress(array[1]);
    printf("\n");
    printAddress(array[2]);
    printf("\n");*/

    //Trying to print with this format causes a segmentation fault
    for(k=0; k<total; k++);
    {
        printAddress(array[k]);
    }
}
```

All my other sorting methods work fine when I print using a for loop.  Here is how I allocated the array and address line in my fill array method:

```
/*Allocate memory for array of Addresses*/
    myAdd = (Address*)malloc((*total)*sizeof(Address));
```

and:

```
fgets(line, sizeof(line), fin);
line_length = strlen(line);
line[line_length-1] = '\0'; line_length--;
myAdd[i].street = malloc(line_length+1);
strcpy(myAdd[i].street, line);
```

Can anybody steer me in the right direction?  It's like I lost the array pointer or something.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: ....And it turns out I am just a dummy.  I had a ';' after my for loop declaration.  Everyone can ignore this question now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a ';' after the for loop declaration.  You have no idea how dumb I feel.

```
//Trying to print with this format causes a segmentation fault
for(k=0; k<total; k++); //<-- ';' 
{
    printAddress(array[k]);
}
```

Should be:

```
for(k=0; k<total; k++)// <-- no ';'
{
    printAddress(array[k]);
}
```

After 5 hours of looking at it, I finally saw it.